# Doxygen configuration on Linux to ignore case sensitivity when put onto windows

Tags: html, linux, windows, doxygen

I am currently using Doxygen 1.5.5 on Linux

Some class documentation is unavailable in the Windows version of my documentation. My library provides several classes, one in uppercase and another in lowercase such as CONE and cone; thus, their class documentation is provided as classCONE.html and classcone.html.

Due to case insensitivity for filenames on Windows systems, the uppercase class documentation overwrites lowercase class documentation when the ZIP file's contents are extracted onto a Windows system. Because the uppercase class documentation is restored last, it thus, overwrites the first file in lowercase with the same name.

I am able to display both of these pages when I host my documentation on a Linux server; however, this is not the case when others extract the contents onto their Windows system.

Is there a way to configure Doxygen to give one of the files a different HTML file name, such as classCONE2.html and to implement that for all links to refer to this page in the Doxygen-generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.5.5 is over 5 years old, but I think even that version provides `CASE_SENSE_NAMES` which you can set to NO to prevent name clashes for output files that only differ in casing.

Comment: Alright i will attempt that change but you do have a good point in stating how hold my version it. Maybe it is time to upgrade!Do you know what things i should look out for when i upgrade doxygen on linux? Will there be any conflicts from an upgrade? I have customized some doxygen configuration files for different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem) post. It explains, how you can turn on case-sensitivity for Windows Systems with 64 Bit. However if you are using Win32 programs, even on 64 Bit systems, you might encounter difficulties.

I would recommend, to try out first doxygens answer, and if does not work out, try my approach.